# Are runon sentences more permissible in legal writing?

Tags: style, legal

In a legal filing, as long as the meaning is not at all ambiguous which seems to be the cardinal objective of legal writing, are runon sentences which may be more cumbersome to read less undesirable than they may be outside of legal writing?

Comment: Legal questions should probably go to somebody such as a lawyer. Writing a legal document might have consequences that require specialist knowledge to get correct.

Comment: I’m sorry but I can’t help thinking your comment is reflective of an attitude toward gaining knowledge that is entirely contrary to the entire spirit of the stack exchange network.

Comment: Legal writing is very precise and poor grammar will reflect poorly.